# How to customize QComboBox with CSS

Tags: python, pyqt

The code below creates `QComboBox` with five items. 
Using `.setStyleSheet()` method the pull-down background color is changed to grey.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
combo=QtGui.QComboBox()
for i in range(5): combo.addItem('%s'%id(i))
combo.setStyleSheet('background-color: grey')
combo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Question: How to get rid of two white bars visible at the top and bottom of ComboBox's pull-down menu?
Here is the screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding` needs to be set to zero along vertical axes:

```
combo.setStyleSheet('background-color: grey; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;')
```

Result:

[image]